# continuity of a function when restricted to closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $X = A \cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are closed subspaces of $X$. Let $f: X \to Y$. Suppose

$$ f|_A : A \to Y $$
$$ f|_B : B \to Y $$

are continuous. Then can we conclude that $f$ must be continuous?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed for every closed $F\subset Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $V\subset Y$ be a closed subset. Its preimage $f^{-1}(V)$ under $f$ can be written as $(f^{-1}(V)\cap A) \,\cup\,(f^{-1}(V)\cap B)$. Observe that
$$f^{-1}(V)\cap A \ =\ (f|_A)^{-1}(V)\,. $$